# how to judge the side from a point to a linestring

Tags: topology, nettopologysuite

I'm working with NTS (NetTopologySuite), I get point geometry and a directed linestring, how to judge the side of the point locate with the linestring? one the left side, right side, or just on the linestring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [CGAlgorithms.ComputeOrientation method](http://nts.sourceforge.net/docs/v1.2/GisSharpBlog.NetTopologySuite.Algorithm.CGAlgorithms.ComputeOrientation.html)